# How to remove a specific column in SQL Server 2008 R2 while generating data only script query of table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database with 4 columns (`col1, col2, col3, col4` datatype `varbinary`)

I  have bound data to all columns, `col4` has important data and this column should not be shared with anyone.

When I use `Generate script` as `Data only` that `col4` should not be included in this script.

Is this possible? If possible can please tell me how to do ..

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried imprting the data into a different table on a test sytem and then wipe the last column then generate scripts off of that.